# Create Reverse "R" for Powerpoint

Tags: drawing, powerpoint

Difficulty creating reverse "R" in powerpoint, i.e. as in

[image]

These directions aren't working, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Rotate-or-flip-a-picture-shape-text-box-or-WordArt-47e482be-dce5-40ba-815f-c0aea4fb7ea7

This is what I tried:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a Dutch office version. Menu names may not be exactly correct, but they should be able to direct you where you need to be.

- Go to format
- Go to Text effects
- Select 3D rotation
- Select Options for 3D rotation
- Change the X axis to 180

This actually rotates the text, rather than the text box.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot flip horizontally a character, in powerpoint, however, you can flip a shape/vector drawing.
So you need to convert your wordart character to a shape.
In order to do that, you can play with the merge/union/combine/fragment functions :

- draw a box on top of your wordart
- put it behind
- select both the R wordart and the box
- menu Format -> merge, then try options like intersect

That will create a shape from your wordart and the box, that you can flip horizontally.

Comment: I found option to `Group`, where is `Merge`? With `Group` it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

If you need just reverse version of 'R' maybe you can use cyrillic letter 'Я' (U+042F). In unicode it's called 'CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER YA'

Comment: How to type this, `U+042F`

Comment: In winword you press alt and then type '042f'. Or you could just copy-paste that letter from my answer.